# How to echo a json multiline string in php

Tags: javascript, json, xml

I am writing a JSON file inside javascript. I want to echo/display $myJson['customer_details']['xml'] just as it is. How can i echo the value of 'xml' though it is multiline string?

Here's the console error btw (Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token)

```
$myJson = {  
       "customer_details" : {  
          "text" : "Customer Details",
          "xml" : "<?xml version="1.0"?> 
                   <customer-details> 
                     <info></info>
                   </customer-details>"
       },
       "car_details" : {  
          "text" : "Car Details",
          "xml" : "<another-xml-here></another-xml-here>"
       }
    }
```

Image: [Here's the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yz9Ra.jpg)

Comment: could you try `var_dump(the json)`

Comment: @PredatorIWD Yes

Comment: That's not valid json, you need double quotes `"` for the keys and values. And this looks like javascript, how is it related to your php question?

Answer (score 1):

```
$myJson = {
```

where is quote?

```
$myJson = "{
```

If you have a string - enclose in quotation marks your string and use json_decode.

```
$myJson = "{
    \"customer_details\" : {
        'text' : 'Customer Details',
          'xml' : '<?xml version=\"1.0\"?> 
                   <customer-details> 
                     <info></info>
                   </customer-details>'
       },
       \"car_details\" : {
        'text' : 'Car Details',
          'xml' : '<another-xml-here></another-xml-here>'
       }
    }";

$arr = json_decode($myJson, true);
echo $arr['customer_details']['xml'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r($myJson['customer_details']['xml];
```

You should treat it like a multi dimensional array. it this does not work try first to decode it like this:

```
$myNewJson=json_decode($myJson);
```

And then go for the print_r with the logic i saw you above. If you feel like getting lost in the array try to print_r it as full so you can see the path by yourself.